# Trick for calculating the 5th order derivative of $(2x^3+1)e^{x^2}$ evaluated at $0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion, binomial-coefficients, mental-arithmetic

Are there any tricks for calculating the 5th order derivative of $(2x^3+1)e^{x^2}$ evaluated at $0$?
I guess it involves binomial expansion but it still seems too complicated.

Comment: Can you use the Maclaurin series of $e^x$?

Comment: $e^x$ expands to $1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} +O(x^3)$ so $e^{x^2}$ expands to $1 + x^2 + \frac{x^4}{2} + O(x^6)$ which is all we need for the fifth order derivative. We only need the $O(x^5)$ terms of $(2x^3+1)e^{x^2}$. Those from $e^{x^2}$ are even order terms so fifth order ones don't result from pairing with  $1$ of $1 + 2x^3$. The only fifth order term is from pairing $x^2$ of $e^{x^2}$ with $2x^3$  of $1 + 2x^3$.  The result is $2x^5$ whose fifth order derivative at $0$ is $2*5!$.

Comment: Thanks! This should be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using serie expansion
$$let : \;f(x)=(1+2x^3)e^{x^2}$$
$$
e^{x^2}＝1＋x^2＋\frac {x^4}{2!}＋{\rm O}(x^5)\\~\\f(x)=(1＋2x^3)e^{x^2}＝(1＋2x^3)(1＋x^2＋\frac {x^4}{2!})＋＋{\rm O}(x^5)＝1＋x^2+2x^3+\frac {1}{2}x^4＋2x^5+{\rm O}(x^5)$$

And therfore :
$$f(x)=f(0)＋\frac {f^{(1)}(0)}{1!}x＋\frac {f^{(2)}(0)}{2!}x^2＋\frac {f^{(3)}(0)}{3!}x^3＋\frac {f^{(4)}(0)}{4!}x^4＋\frac {f^{(5)}(0)}{5!}x^5＋{\rm O}(x^5)$$

We note that:
$$\frac {f^{(5)}(0)}{5!}＝2\implies\;f^{(5)}(0)＝2×5!=240$$

**So, the fifth-degree derivative at  x=0 is:240**

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it think about
$\frac{d^5}{dx^5}(fg)$ if you derive once you get $f'g+fg'$ twice you get $f''g+2f'g'+g''$ three times $f'''g+3f''g'+3f'g''+fg'''$ in general

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(fg) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} f^{(k)}g^{(n-k)}$$
Follows the binomial expansion. The good thing about your case is $(2x^3+1)$ vanish after 4 derivatives. Also, after the first derivative when you plug $0$ it will be zero! so what are the remaining terms? On the other hand after the first derivative of $e^{x^2}$ you get zero when you plug $x=0$ so?